# What a strange behavior in AutoComplete in DataGridViewCombobox column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am using the (`EditingControlShowing`) event to Enable AutoComplete in DataGridViewComboBox Column.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,  DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
    {
        ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)e.Control;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteMode =  System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    }
}
```

But it has a strange behavior, when I type some characters then I leave the cell (Tab or right key), the value did not change.
But if I repeat that, the value will change.
From [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/UploadFile/houssam11350/08312012091630AM/autocompleteproblem.zip), you can download the source code and (EXE) video that explains the problem.

Could you please help me to make it work correctly?

Comment: Interesting issue and nice work on the fix! I've added an alternative fix that uses a little bit less code that you may find useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that for that first entry into the combobox the tab no longer triggers the commit of the value. No idea why this is so, but it appears that handling `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` and committing the edit fixes it.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You could also check here to see if the cell in question is the combobox
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this :

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
    {
        ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)e.Control;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        combo.Validated -= new EventHandler(combo_Validated);
        combo.Validated += new EventHandler(combo_Validated);

    }
}

public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    if (src == null)
        return null;
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}

void combo_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Object selectedItem = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(col.ValueMember))
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = GetPropValue(selectedItem, col.ValueMember);
    else
       dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = selectedItem;

}
```