# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn text values not updating (integers do)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridviewcomboboxcell

My first post, as I can't find the answer to this out there.

I have a data bound GridView with a bunch of ComboBoxes.  They correctly display the value from the underlying table, and the correct values appear in the drop down lists.  1 of the Comboboxes has an int .valuemember, and everything works great for it.  The other ComboBox has string .valuemember, and when I select a different value in the combobox it does not update to the bound table.

They are bound and updated with the same code from the same table and the same grid.  I am specifically binding to a ESRI ArcGIS file.  It seems to be correctly bound, and I have used it for other projects successfully.  It does again display and update changes in all columns, and will accept changes to integer based rows; therefore I have, maybe stupidly, ruled this out.

Not sure what I need to do to make string .valuemember value to update.

I am missing something simple I guess but I don't know what it is.  Here is some sample code.

```vb
Domain1 As BindingList(Of Domaintype)
Domain2 As BindingList(Of Domaintype)
GridView.DataSource = pBindingSource

'add the columns desired
    GridView.Columns.Add(CreateComboBoxColumn("Column1Value", "Type1", Domain1 , "NonCodedIntValue"))
    GridView.Columns.Add(CreateComboBoxColumn("Column2Value", "Type2", Domain2 , "NonCodedCharValue"))

Private Function CreateComboBoxColumn(ByVal ColumnName As String, ByVal AliasName As String, ByRef DomainName As BindingList(Of Domaintype), ByVal pValueMember As String) As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    CreateComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    With CreateComboBoxColumn
        .DataPropertyName = ColumnName
        .HeaderText = AliasName
        .ReadOnly = False
    End With
    With CreateComboBoxColumn
        .DataSource = DomainName
        .DisplayMember = "CodedValue"
        .ValueMember = pValueMember
    End With
    Return CreateComboBoxColumn
End Function

Private Sub GridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If GridView.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        GridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub

Public Class Domaintype
    Private CodedValue As String
    Private NonCodedInt As Nullable(Of Short)
    Private NonCodedChar As String

    'adds a new coded value based on a sent non-coded and coded value
    Public Sub New(ByVal SentCodedValue As String, ByVal SentNonCoded As Nullable(Of Short), Optional ByVal SentNonCodedChar As String = Nothing)
        CodedValue = SentCodedValue
        NonCodedInt = SentNonCoded
        NonCodedChar = SentNonCodedChar
    End Sub
    'Gets or sets the coded value of a domain
    Public ReadOnly Property CodedValue() As String
        Get
            Return CodedValue
        End Get
    End Property
    'gets or sets the non-coded value of a domain
    Public ReadOnly Property NonCodedIntValue() As Nullable(Of Short)
        Get
            Return NonCodedInt
        End Get
    End Property

    'gets or sets the non-coded value of a domain
    Public ReadOnly Property NonCodedCharValue() As String
        Get
            Return NonCodedChar
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I was trying to set up something similar to what I'm sure you're using, but it's hard to guess exactly what the Domaintype object looks like. Also, what is pBindingSource equal to?

Comment: I updated to include the Domaintype class, and discuss the pBindingSource more.

Comment: Richard, I kind of get the idea of what you're looking to accomplish and have tried to get something up to at least be able to test your code, but to no avail. My guess is that you may have an easier time if you were to just utilize a datatable to represent your data and bind it to the gridview. The columns in the datatable would be of type "Domaintype" and be bound to your Domaintype objects. Let me know if you are still having issues and perhaps I could get all the needed info from you to replicate your setup (or as close as possible).

Comment: I came across your question in my search and this was the answer to my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216530/what-a-strange-behavior-in-autocomplete-in-datagridviewcombobox-column?rq=1